# Verify my proof: $\cup (\mathcal F \cap \mathcal G) \subseteq (\cup \mathcal F) \cap (\cup \mathcal G) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm self learning from book "How to Prove it" by Velleman (3rd edition). I don't have access to a math professor, so I need a little help from the community. Please verify my proof.

Problem 18 pag. 140

> Suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are families of sets. Prove that $\cup (\mathcal F \cap \mathcal G) \subseteq (\cup   \mathcal F) \cap (\cup \mathcal G) $

**Proof**. Let's introduce the following notations $A = \cup (\mathcal F \cap \mathcal G) $ and $ B = (\cup   \mathcal F) \cap (\cup \mathcal G) $. We must prove that $A \subseteq B$, this means that if we take an arbitrary element $x$ from $A$ it must be also an element from $B$. $x \in A$ means that there is a set $z$ which is a member of both families of sets $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$, so $z \in \mathcal F$ and $z \in \mathcal G$ and $x \in z$. Let's mark this sentence as (1).
$x \in B$ means that there is a set $v$ which is a member of $\mathcal F$ and a set $w$ which is a member of $\mathcal G$ so $v \in \mathcal F$ and $w \in \mathcal G$ and $x \in v \cap w$. Let's mark this sentence as (2). Now observe the difference from (1), $z$ is a member of both $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$, but $v \in \mathcal F$ and $w \in \mathcal G$, as a particular case $v=w=z$. But generally speaking elements from $A$ are a subset of elements from $B$ $\blacksquare $

Comment: Your proof looks good. Based on them direction your notation seems to be going, I suggest using calligraphic fonts for sets of sets, capital roman letters for sets and lower case roman for members of sets. It's not completely standard, but it threw off my expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the logic, you are completely right.

Not that I want to suggest writing too much formalism (on the contrary, proofs drowning in "$\Rightarrow$" and "$\therefore$" and such are awful to read!), but for my personal taste, this is  too wordy (in particularly those "let's mark this sentence ..." parts, and the "$v=w=z$" may even be confusing) -
Compare with this (just a style *suggestion*):

> **Proof.** Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup (\mathcal F\cap \mathcal G)$. Then by definition of $\bigcup$, there exists $y\in \mathcal F\cap \mathcal G$ with $x\in y$. By definition of $\cap$,  we have both $y\in\mathcal F$ and $y\in\mathcal G$. But $x\in y\in\mathcal F$ implies $x\in\bigcup F$, and $x\in y\in\mathcal G$ implies $x\in\bigcup G$. From $x\in\bigcup F$ and $x\in \bigcup\mathcal G$, we get $x\in (\bigcup \mathcal F)\cap (\bigcup \mathcal G)$.
>
> So in summary, $x\in \bigcup (\mathcal F\cap \mathcal G)$ implies $x\in (\bigcup \mathcal F)\cap (\bigcup \mathcal G)$, in other words, $\bigcup (\mathcal F\cap \mathcal G)\subseteq (\bigcup \mathcal F)\cap (\bigcup \mathcal G)$, as was to be shown. $\square$